# Get the last function argument in typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, destructuring

I'm trying to destructure arguments of a function that only cares for the last parameter passed in, binding its value to variable `next`; the following works fine in plain js, node 10:

```
> function f(...{length, [length - 1]: next}) { console.log(next) }
> f(1,2,3,4)
4
```

However same construct in typescript gives me:

```
error TS2501: A rest element cannot contain a binding pattern.

function (...{length, [length - 1]: next}) {
             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quite interesting question, because basically the statement - "TS is superset of JS" does not work here.

It turns out, that when we try to use binding pattern in destructing and spread operator at the same time, we'll get an error:

[image]

Currently in TS diagnostic messages file there is an explicit error for [A_rest_element_cannot_contain_a_binding_pattern_2501](https://github.com/Microsoft/typescript-build2016-demos/blob/master/controlFlow-nonNull/TypeScript-controlFlowTypes/diagnosticMessages.generated.json#L408)

Also there is an [open Pull Request](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/26017/files#diff-e99e96560efadd7a4a06212281a4ef60) and in TypeScript repo which probably will solve this "issue" (not sure that it's an issue or something else).

But you can always choose this approach for your task:

```
function f(...args) {
    console.log(args[args.length - 1]);
}
```

Comment: fwiw, (...args) => {const {length, [length - 1]: next} = args} compiles just fine